# FindOne does not work using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netbeans, spring-data

Good evening, I'm having problems with *Spring*. `findOne` is returning the following error:

> org.springframework.data.repository.query.querybyexampleexecutor can
>   not be applied to given types;
>
> Required: Example
>
> Found Long

Below a little code to see if I can help. :) Thank you

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/produtos")
public class ProdutoResource {

    @Autowired
    private ProdutoServico produtoServico;

    public ProdutoResource(ProdutoServico produtoServico){
        this.produtoServico = produtoServico;
    }


    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Produto> findAll(){
        return this.produtoServico.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{/id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Produto find(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){
        return this.produtoServico.find(id);

    }
```

.

```
public interface ProdutoServico {

    public List<Produto> findAll();
    public Produto find(Long id);
    public Produto create(Produto produto);
    public Produto update();
    public void delete();

}
```

.

```
@Service
public class ProdutoServiceImpl implements ProdutoServico {

    @Autowired
    private ProdutoRepository produtoRepository;

    public ProdutoServiceImpl(ProdutoRepository produtoRepository){
        this.produtoRepository = produtoRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Produto> findAll() {
    return this.produtoRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Produto find(Long id) {
        return this.produtoRepository.findOne(id);
    //   return null;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Edited

```
@Entity
public class Produto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String nome;

    @Column
    private Integer qtd;

    @Column
    private Date dataCriacao;

    getters an setters omitted

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "id=" + this.id + ", nome=" + this.nome + ", qtd=" + this.qtd + ", dataCriacao=" + this.dataCriacao + '}';
    }

}
```

.

```
    @Repository

public interface ProdutoRepository extends JpaRepository<Produto, Long>{

}
```

Comment: Could you post your ``ProdutoRepository`` class?

Comment: I edited with what you asked for. thank you.

Comment: ups, we'll need the QueryByExampleExecutor, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `ProdutoRepository.findOne(Example<S> var1)` takes a `Produto` and return the matching result.

```
Produto p = new Produto();
p.setName("something");
Example<Produto> match = Example.of(p);
Optional<Produto> result = produtoRepository.findOne(match);
```

But looking at your code, you are trying to get `Produto` for a given primary key value (Produto Id). Then you should use:

```
Optional<Produto> result = produtoRepository.findById(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
value="{/id}"
```

to

```
value="/{id}"
```

inside the @RequestMapping of your controller and also check whether the datatype of primary key value in your table is same as datatype of id in the model class. Hope this helps your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As part of Spring Data Kay (2.0) the method `findOne(ID id)` was renamed to `findById(ID id)`. Therefore the only remaining `findOne` Method that remains is the one that takes an `Example` as argument.

- For details about the change see: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-944
- For documentation about query by example: 
  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, it was as follows:

```
@Override
public Produto find(Long id) {
    Optional<Produto> produto = produtoRepository.findById(id);

    Produto prod = new Produto();

    prod.setId(produto.get().getId());
    prod.setNome(produto.get().getNome());
    prod.setDataCriacao(produto.get().getDataCriacao());
    prod.setQtd(produto.get().getQtd());

    return prod;
   }
```

In postman

> > {
> >        "id": 2,
> >
> > "nome": "Produto2",
> >
> > "qtd": 50,
> >
> > "dataCriacao": null
> >     }

Note: The dataCriacao is actually null.

Answer (score -1):

You need specify method type for request mapping

add method = RequestMethod.GET as below

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value = "{/id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Produto find(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){
        return this.produtoServico.find(id);

    }
```

That should resolve API layer issue. For more please add model and repository class

**UPDATE**

Use below -- most efficient for CRUD (CrudRepository)

```
 @Repository

    public interface ProdutoRepository extends CrudRepository<Produto, Long>{

    }
```

Comment: I edited with what you asked for. thank you.
I tried it that way and it did not work.

Comment: Can you please add your whole service layer ? Why are you using this.repository ?